# Simulink: Save the max value of a system and update it every time it gets a new value

Tags: matlab, save, max, simulink

I have a car which is driving with a constant speed. To go from 0 till 100kmh it need 20sec. I could represent it like this in simulink:
[image]
Here I gave as input 10 kmh has to be reach and as you see it need 2 Sec to reach it:
[image].
But I want that when I run the simulink again (with 10 again as input) it goes from 10 to 20. I tried the block max to get the actual max from the system (10 in this case) to give it add it to the new input to get 20 but the "max" block provides the same function of the time and not a value (Scalar).
Does anyone have an Idea this Issue? or it is a matter of how I am simulating it?
some explanation from the model: the first saturation is to keep the speed between 0 and 100, the second one is for the speed (+-100/20). the integrator linited is to limit the integral between 0 and 100

Thanks in advance

Comment: Individual re-runs of the model are distinct, the `memory` block won't remember from one run to the other. You could use a variable name in the constant block instead of a numeric value, initialise that variable to something before the first run and update it (maybe with a ToWorkspace) block at the end of your simulation. Then as long as you don't clear your workspace in between runs the value will persist

Comment: Thanks for yout answer @Wolfie. in fact I first tried with "To Workspace" but with this method, you first need to run the simualtion for the first time without the variable of "to worksoace" e.g. out.OldVal.Data otherwise you will get the error that there is no variable called "OldVal" if you have named it "OldVal" for exemple. That it why I tried it that way
Or is there a way to use the value from "To Workspace" only "if it exists"? I didn't find that out in Simulink

Comment: You can manually just create that variable by defining it in the command window or a script before the first sim